Problem passing props to a component through <Route/> and <Link to={}/>
I have a problem with my React app and I would appreciate any help.
I decided to define the states and the routes in the App.jsx and pass the props directly through the routes:
function App() {
  
  const EMPTY_FORM = {
    checkIn: "",
    checkOut: "",
  };
 
  const [hotelParameters, setHotelParameters] = useState(EMPTY_FORM);
  const [adultCount, setAdultCount] = useState(0);
  const [roomCount, setRoomCount] = useState(0); `  

  .... ...etc... rest of the code.....

  .... 

    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/Spain/*"
        element={
          <SpainPage
            hotelParameters={hotelParameters}
            adultCount={adultCount}
            roomCount={roomCount}
          />
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </div>
 );
}

export default App;

But when I navigate to the SpainPage, I get undefined.
The destination is the third step in the app, and to get to the SpainPage I use a <Link to= {}/> inside the Trips component:
<Link
   to={{
     pathname:
       selectedImage === "Spain"
         ? "/Spain/*"
         : selectedImage === "Italy"
         ? "/Italy/*"
         : selectedImage === "France"
         ? "/France/"
         : null,
   }}
 >
   <img
     src={
       selectedImage === "Spain"
         ? SpainImage
         : selectedImage === "Italy"
         ? ItalyImage
         : selectedImage === "France"
         ? FranceImage
         :  null
     }
     className="figure-img img-fluid rounded"
     alt={selectedImage}
   />
 </Link>

The Trips actually receives successfully the props this way:
export default function Trips() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { hotelParameters, adultCount, roomCount } = location.state;

The problem is that the SpainPage does not receive these props at all.
I used two ways to receive the props:


export default function SpainPage({ hotelParameters, adultCount, roomCount }) 



import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Trips() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { hotelParameters, adultCount, roomCount } = location.state;



I also tried passing the props inside the <Link to={}>:
<Link
  to={{
    pathname:
      selectedImage === "Spain"
        ? "/Spain/*"
        : selectedImage === "Italy"
        ? "/Italy/*"
        : selectedImage === "France"
        ? "/France/"
        : null,
    state: {
      hotelParameters: hotelParameters,
      adultCount: adultCount,
      roomCount: roomCount,
    },
  }}
>

